# How do you remove a hyperlink from a cell in Numbers '08 version 1.0.3?

Tags: numbers, url

I have an address in a cell which is hyperlinked. I've also searched other posts on the topic and the selecting text and "right-clicking" does not bring up a menu with how to remove the link. I'd really appreciate some help if anyone's worked out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Select the hyperlinked text then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.  This will bring up the Link dialog where you can remove the link via the **Remove** button.

One can also change the link here as well.

[image: Remove hyperlink]